# Travelling to Delhi from Berlin with transit in London Heathrow

Tags: visas, uk, transit, lhr, german-residents

I am an Indian citizen traveling to Delhi via the UK. I have a Permanent Residence in Germany along with US and Canadian visas.

Do I need a transit visa as the ticket is issued by British Airways and Virgin Atlantic? Do I need to go landside because of 2 different carriers?

[image]

Edit: Also, what happens in case of a missed connection as the airlines don't have a codeshare agreement. Does the interline agreement cover missed connections in such a booking?

Comment: For clarity, is the trip on one PNR?

Comment: @Traveller I haven't booked the ticket yet but I called Travelocity and they said it will be a single ticket.